# How to dynamically concat string with props?

Tags: reactjs

I need to build useState to send date to nested components.
I tried `` onChange={(e) => `${"setValue" + props.id}`(e.target.value)`; ``
but it show me an error that in `'"".concat("setValue" + props.id)(e.target.value)'}`
value equal setValue1, so it was I expected.
but when I use it, it not show an error, but not work at all.

Comment: I'm not sure about what you're trying to achieve but might it be this? 
`\`setValue${props.id}${e.target.value}\``

Comment: I create a calculator In a table something like ``` data.map((props) => (
<tr>
<td>{props.value}</td> ```
and want to give improvement that some date client can change
like
```
<td><input type="number"  value={ Value ? Value :  props.data} onChange={(e) => `setValue${props.id}${e.target.value}` }  ```
but this code do not run.